# How to get reference type variable of array of primitives?

Tags: c#, oop, primitive-types

So my question can be described by simply code:

```
        double[] doubles = new double[]  { 0.01, 0.01, };
        var w2 = doubles;
        w2 = null;
        //doubles still has values
```

I know about difference between structs and classes:

> If we copy the objects to new variables:
>   Point p2 = p1;
>   Form f2 = f1;
>   p2, being a struct, becomes an independent copy of p1, with its own separate fields. But in the case of f2, all we’ve copied is a reference, with the result that both f1 and f2 point to the same object.

(source : http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

but is there any way of getting referenced type that let me set w2 to null by setting doubles=null without using casting to `List<double>`, `unsafe{}`?

Comment: The type is just `double[]`... could you explain what you mean by *referenced type*?

Comment: In C++ we have safe pointers that can do that job, in C# we not without using that tricky unsafe that can easly make w2 null

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski The Reference type variable is such type of variable in C# that holds the reference of memory address instead of value. class, interface, delegate, array are the reference type. When you create object of particular class with new keyword, a space is created in the managed heap that holds the reference of classes.

Comment: @Taumantis I know C# very well, thank you, so do I know this kind of very basic stuff :) But I just can't make sense of what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Your comment "w2 still has values". Is that good? Bad? Are you looking for a way such that `doubles` and `w2` are *aliases*? If so, then that is not possible with built-in C# types, though creating a container class is very easy to do. As well, you can use `out`/`ref` parameters to alias parameters to an argument.

Comment: @Taumantis Your English is fine, I think you were just missing a key step :) In any case, it's not really possible to do what you want, since while `double` and `w2` refer to the same object, they're otherwise completely separate variables. It's not really clear why you would need to be able to affect one by assigning to the other; maybe you could describe your actual problem (aside from "micro-optimizations")?

Comment: @dlev I have access to only one method where I can have only one paramter that is acceptable by some very old version of framework 2.0. In normal world the normal oil platforms have all their programs done with C, but on that one some strange men impelent C# controlers. The problem is that operations are done on very small amount of memory, so copy of that double[] is not possible

Comment: The code wasn't copying the `double[]`. It only copied the reference (pointer) to it. There was never more than one copy of the data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are right i misseplaced variables in questions now its ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't actually mean `doubles` and `w2` would be in the same scope. I'm guessing that you are passing `doubles` into some other scope, and that you want to pass the reference instead of a copy so that you can modify `doubles` from that other context?

```
double[] doubles = new double[] { 1, 2, 3}; 

SomeMethod(ref doubles);


// This will return true
Console.WriteLine(doubles == null);


private static void SomeMethod(ref double[] w2)
{
    w2 = null;
}
```

Comment: The power of syntax, i'll check. I think that could work if only w2 have lower size than doubles. And i hope 2.0 will run with it. If yes i will check the answere

Comment: Also see: [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what you want but if you want to programmatically get the type of w2 then just do this:

```
Type w2_type = w2.GetType();
```

You can add w2_type to the watch list it should have a value of "{System.Double[]}"

Comment: nope, like i said in comments i need somehow get pointer of doubles variable